# Urlpatterns: category/subcategory/article-slug

Tags: django

Django==3.2.5

```
re_path(r'^.*/.*/<slug:slug>/$', Single.as_view(), name="single"),
```

Here I'm trying to organize the following pattern: category/subcategory/article-slug. Category and subcategory are not identifying anything in this case. Only slug is meaningful.

Now I try:

```
http://localhost:8000/progr/django/1/
```

And get this:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/progr/django/1/
Using the URLconf defined in articles_project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
^.*/.*/<slug:slug>/$ [name='single']
articles/
^static/(?P<path>.*)$
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, progr/django/1/, didn’t match any of these.

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing the `path` and `re_path` functions, `re_path` has no path converters and only uses *regex*, hence when you write `<slug:slug>` that literally means a url having that *exact* string there, instead you want to capture the pattern `[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+` (which is the pattern Django uses for a slug). Also using `.*` in your pattern will likely cause you problems, as it can match `/` too and likely cause some of your other urls to be never used, instead you might want to use `[^/]*`. So you likely want to change your pattern to:

```py
re_path(r'^[^/]*/[^/]*/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$', Single.as_view(), name="single"),
```

This still feels a little problematic to me as it matches two arbitrary patterns and doesn't capture and pass them to the view, you might in fact simply want to shift to using `path` and capture these patterns too:

```py
from django.urls import path


path('<str:some_string1>/<str:some_string2>/<slug:slug>/', Single.as_view(), name="single"),
```